# Is there a way to convert an .eot to .woff or call another file in css

Tags: css, web, fonts, tailwind-css, font-face

I have this big chunk of text that looks something like this:

```css
url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAHnQABMAAAABHZAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGRlRNAAABqAAAABwAAAAcbWcNJUdERUYAAAHEAAAANQAAADgF/) format("woff")
```

I would like to rather call the text like so `src: url("Font.woff");`

I don't have the woff file for the font, can I convert the .eot file I have to woff? If so how? Otherwise is there way to call a .txt file from my styles.css so I don't have this monstrosity paragraph in there.

Answer (score 0):

CSS: Using @fontface

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat'; /* Gewünschter Name */
src: url('../../../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.eot');
/* für IE9 */
src: url('../../../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), /* für IE6-IE8 */
url('../../../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.woff') format('woff'), /* für moderne Browser */
url('../../../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
/* für Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was drag your eof into google chrome's url and it will save it for you as a .wof - that simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).